# How to convert nested loops to a one-liner?

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-loops, flatmap

Is that possible to convert below for loops to a one-liner using the `stream` api?

```
List<QuestionAnswer> questionAnswerCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

for (Question question : questions) {
    for (String answer : question.getAnswers()) {
        questionAnswerCombinations.add(new QuestionAnswer(question.getLabel(), answer ));
    }
}
```

I though of using `flatMap` but I loose the `question` when I do that.

What is the correct way of converting this nesting loops to a one-liner?

**Note:** I can add the data structure of `Question` class if needed, but there is no complication other than what is inferred from the usage.

**Update:** What I'm trying to do is basically collect all question+answer combinations into another list. As in:

```
Question 1
-Answer a
-Answer b
-Answer c
Question 2
-Answer x
-Answer y

Question 1, Answer a
Question 1, Answer b
Question 1, Answer c
Question 2, Answer x
Question 2, Answer y
```

Comment: how does your flatmap looks like?

Comment: Does my update on the question answer your question? @StefanBeike

Comment: `questions.stream.flatMap(q -> q.getAnswers().stream().map(ans -> new QuestionAnswer(q.getLabel(), ans))).collect(Collectors.toList())` Does that work ?

Comment: Yes @VenkataRaju. You may post it as an answer so I can accept it. Since you were the first one to post it I believe it would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
questions
    .stream
    .flatMap(qn -> qn.getAnswers()
                     .stream()
                     .map(ans -> new QuestionAnswer(qn.getLabel(), ans)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
question.forEach(q -> q.getAnswers().forEach(a -> questionAnswerCombinations.add(new QuestionAnswer(q.getLabel(), a)))
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer using forEach or a for(value : values) is the same and the the forEach notation is less readable.

Comment: well, I agree that it is more or less the same, not sure about readability, but the question is about converting the loop in one line using stream api, and the response is pertinent. (Anyway, just trying to help, if there is a better way, I'll be happy to learn)  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a valid one liner, but I was curious about the mapping solutions.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like below could help using **forEach** loop:

```
questions.stream().forEach(question -> {question.getAnswers().stream().forEach(answer -> { questionAnswerCombinations.add(new QuestionAnswer(question.getLabel(), answer)); }); });
```

**Edited:**

or using **flatMap**:

```
questionAnswerCombinations = questions.stream().flatMap(question -> question.getAnswers().stream().map(answer -> new QuestionAnswer(question.getLabel(), answer))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```